# Get Google Maps v3 corner coordinates from iFrame to parent page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with marker data pulled from my database on my website inside an iFrame. I know that with Maps v3 it is possible to get the new corner GPS coordinates when the map is moved in JavaScript.

Is it possible to pass this map information from the map page inside the iFrame to the parent page so I can change the content on the parent page to match what the map is showing with JavaScript? Both pages are on my same server. I imagine that worst case scenario I can just have the JavaScript write the map corner info to a session variable and read that on the parent, but is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show any HTML or code, so I can't be specific, but it's pretty straightforward to get information from an iFrame.

Suppose `frameId` is the ID of your iFrame and `mapId` is the ID of the map in that iFrame. Then:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

You now have the iFrame document and can do the usual:

```
var map = iframeDoc.getElementById('mapId');
var bounds = map.getBounds();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I guess the main point of my question was I didn't know how to communicate JavaScript variables inside/outside the frame.